# Html Iframe Excel , get a hyperlink in the excel to open a new tab or window

Tags: javascript, html, excel, iframe

I have a excel file I turned into a .mht file, and I am embedding it successfully in a html page using iframe. Now the excel file has hyperlinks inside it. I am wondering If I can have it to where when a person clicks on a hyperlink inside the excel file it will open up a new tab in the web browser or just open up a new browser window. Can this be done through coding inside the iframe or do I have to do some kind of coding inside the excel file ?

Posting what the html code is if I can edit it or add a property to it if someone knows. Maybe I may need to use something besides iframe to get it to work on a html page.

```
<iframe src="LinktoFile.mht" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>
```

Comment: i don't understand what you're asking; do you want the tab to open within the iframe or what? Have you tried clicking on the hyperlinks? What happens?

Comment: When I click on the hyperlinks it opens up in the iframe which I do not want it to do. What I want is when someone clicks on a hyperlink inside the iframe that has the excel spreadsheet inside is to have it open up a new tab or a new window if I have to set it to be forced that is fine.

Comment: a new tab out of the iframe

Comment: Yes. I understood the first time, but I'm having dinner. Later!

Comment: Ahh okay that is fine later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

any file that you convert/ save as from excel can easily be edited (using notepad even). ADvisable that you removable the microsoft auto-generated css, but the main thing is that you add a `target ="_blank` in your hyperlink html. This will make the hyperlinks open in a new window.

I know it works with html files but i don't see why mht files should differ greatly (and besides, why make life more difficult? Just save as a html file..)

Comment: That makes the most sense actually just have to find it and make the changes

Comment: and changes made how did I forget I can do that with the html pages to begin is beyond me but thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I [read](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MHTML) that .MHT is a "Mime HTML" file, a kind of html archive.  The browser support for it seems limited.  If you're ok with that read on...

As long as the parent html file and the mht file are on the same domain, you might be able to add to/modify the DOM of the mht file.  I don't know for sure.

Here is a test you can try.  Modify your iframe tag with an id, and then put the script block right after it.  The result should be that all  tags in the iframe open in a new tab.  If that doesn't happen please check the browser console for any errors and report back.

```
<iframe id='xl' src="LinktoFile.mht" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>
<script>
$('#xl').on('load', function () {
  $('#xl').contents().find('a').attr('target', '_blank');
});
</script>
```

Comment: Would changing the file to a html be better because I can do that. When I added that code it still is opening from Iframe. On the console it says that it is expecting an object which is asking for a .html version of the file.

Comment: Would a object tag be better maybe or switching the file to a htm file?

Comment: Try the htm version with the same script

Comment: Same results it is still opening in a new page inside the iframe vs a new outside tab or outside window.

Comment: Can you check the error console please, the test file I wrote is working ok.

Comment: Okay posting the errors I am seeing in chrome
Refused to display 'https://website.com' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.
website:1 GET https://tableau/ net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_RESPONSE

Comment: So the main html file and the "excel" file have to be on the same domain.  I don't think serverless (local) files will work either because of same origin policy.

Comment: but when there in the same domain it will work then ?

Comment: or can the same origin policy be change ?